# Performing Core Data Operations in self created multiple threads to save processing time

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, parallel-processing

I have surfed a lot about performing core data operations in multiple threads but no good luck to solve my problem.

My code is such that I have to download a csv file after every ten minutes which contains each entry of 10 seconds. This file once downloaded is parsed and the contents are saved in database and then files are removed as then, when needed, I can fetch data from database.

Now, I have a huge existing content of more than a month for now which may extend to years also as time passes by, performing this huge task of saving new files to database and fetching objects from core data into an array for already downloaded files using a single thread is causing a huge processing time. Also, views in app needs to be adjusted with all previous data (They are basically plots of quantity vs time).

How can I achieve this in multiple threads and optimize my code processing time and reduce UI Blockage to minimum?

Please note that : Performing the task in background thread is not my concern as I in any case have to show graphs on the basis of total data. Please provide valuable advices.

EDIT: PERFORMED SOME MULTITHREADING
HERE IS THE NEW CODE,

```
- (void) downloadFiles:(NSString *)dataPath{



__block AppDelegate *appD = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

backgroundMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

[backgroundMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[appD managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];



if (parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentDay) {

    parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentDay = nil;

}



if (parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentMonth) {

    parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentMonth = nil;

}



if (parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentYear) {

    parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentYear = nil;

}

parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentMonth = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentYear = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



dispatch_group_t d_group = dispatch_group_create();





for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= (self.filesListArray.count - 1); i++) {



    NSString *filePathOnPhone = [dataPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", [[self.filesListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"kCFFTPResourceName"]]];



    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ParsedInfiDetails"];



    NSString *nameToGet = [[self.filesListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"kCFFTPResourceName"];



    NSLog(@"File Check: %@", nameToGet);

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName = %@", nameToGet];

    [fetch setPredicate:predicate];



    NSError *error = nil;



    NSArray *results = [backgroundMOC executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];



    NSArray *definedResults = [results copy];

    if(definedResults && (definedResults.count !=0)) {

        NSLog(@"Entities with that name: %@", results);

        @autoreleasepool {



            NSArray *result = [[definedResults sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modDate" ascending:YES]]] copy];



            NSDate *specificDate = [NSDate date];



            NSMutableArray *sortedDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSMutableArray *sortedDateCurrentYearArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSMutableArray *sortedDateCurrentMonthArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i = 0; i < result.count; i++) {

                NSManagedObject *obj = [result objectAtIndex:i];

                NSDate *objDate = [obj valueForKey:@"modDate"];

                NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];



                NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian componentsInTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"] fromDate:objDate];

                NSInteger day = [components day];

                NSInteger month = [components month];

                NSInteger year = [components year];



                NSDateComponents *specificComps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:specificDate];

                NSInteger specificDay = [specificComps day];

                NSInteger specificMonth = [specificComps month];

                NSInteger specificYear = [specificComps year];



                if(day == 24){



                }



                if (day == specificDay && month == specificMonth && year == (specificYear-2000)) {

                    [sortedDateArray addObject:obj];

                }



                NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];

                NSDateComponents *componentsForToday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:todayDate];

                NSInteger currentMonth = [componentsForToday month];

                NSInteger currentYear = [componentsForToday year];





                if (year == (currentYear-2000)) {

                    [sortedDateCurrentYearArray addObject:obj];

                }



                if (year == (currentYear -2000) && month == currentMonth) {

                    [sortedDateCurrentMonthArray addObject:obj];

                }

            }



            NSMutableArray *sortedTimedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sortedDateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modTime" ascending:YES]]]];



            NSMutableArray *sortedTimedCurrentYearArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sortedDateCurrentYearArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modTime" ascending:YES]]]];



            NSMutableArray *sortedTimedCurrentMonthArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sortedDateCurrentMonthArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modTime" ascending:YES]]]];







            [parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentDay addObjectsFromArray:sortedTimedArray];

            [parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentYear addObjectsFromArray:sortedTimedCurrentYearArray];

            [parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentMonth addObjectsFromArray:sortedTimedCurrentMonthArray];

        }

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

        NSString *threadName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld THREAD", (long)i];

        dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create([threadName UTF8String], NULL);





        dispatch_group_async(d_group, myQueue, ^{

            NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundMOC1;

            backgroundMOC1 = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

            [backgroundMOC1 setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[appD managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

            NSLog(@"Entered Thread ");



            BOOL success = [appD.ftpManager downloadFile:[[self.filesListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"kCFFTPResourceName"] toDirectory:[NSURL URLWithString:dataPath] fromServer:srv];



            if (success) {

//                dispatch_group_async(d_group, myQueue, ^{

                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [appD.ftpManager progress];

                NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", [[self.filesListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"kCFFTPResourceName"]]];



                CHCSVParser *parser = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

                [parser parse];

                NSMutableArray *currentFileComponentsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];

                NSMutableArray *parsedDetailsEntitiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (int j = 1; j <= (currentFileComponentsArray.count-1); j++) {





                    NSArray *detailsArray = [currentFileComponentsArray objectAtIndex:j];

                    if (!(detailsArray.count < 32)) {

                        NSManagedObject *parsedDetails = [NSEntityDescription

                                                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ParsedInfiDetails"

                                                          inManagedObjectContext:[appD managedObjectContext]];

                        NSString *totalDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [detailsArray objectAtIndex:0], [detailsArray objectAtIndex:1]];

                        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

                        NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

                        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

                        NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:totalDateString];

                        [parsedDetails setValue:startDate forKey:@"modDate"];

                        [parsedDetails setValue:startDate forKey:@"modTime"];

                        ———————————————————————PERFORM PARSEDDETAILS STATEMENTS----------------





                        NSError *error;



                        NSLog(@"Saved File in Database: %@", [[self.filesListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"kCFFTPResourceName"]);

                        NSLog(@"Saved thread");

                        if (![backgroundMOC1 save:&error]) {

                            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

                        }

                        else{

                            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

                                //if the download fails, we try to delete the empty file created by the stream.

                                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];

                                //when data is stored in coredata remove the downloaded file.

                            }

                            [parsedDetailsEntitiesArray addObject:parsedDetails];



                        }



                    }





                }

                NSSet *set = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:parsedDetailsEntitiesArray];

                [self.relevantInverId setValue:set forKey:@"infiDetails"];



                NSDate *specificDate = [NSDate date];

                @autoreleasepool {

                    NSMutableArray *sortedDateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                    NSMutableArray *sortedDateCurrentYearArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                    NSMutableArray *sortedDateCurrentMonthArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



                    for (int i = 0; i < parsedDetailsEntitiesArray.count; i++) {

                        NSManagedObject *obj = [parsedDetailsEntitiesArray objectAtIndex:i];

                        NSDate *objDate = [obj valueForKey:@"modDate"];



                        NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];



                        NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian componentsInTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"] fromDate:objDate];

                        NSInteger day = [components day];

                        NSInteger month = [components month];

                        NSInteger year = [components year];



                        NSDateComponents *specificComps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:specificDate];

                        NSInteger specificDay = [specificComps day];

                        NSInteger specificMonth = [specificComps month];

                        NSInteger specificYear = [specificComps year];



                        if(day == 24){





                        }

                        if (day == specificDay && month == specificMonth && year == (specificYear-2000)) {

                            [sortedDateArray addObject:obj];

                        }



                        NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];

                        NSDateComponents *componentsForToday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:todayDate];

                        NSInteger currentMonth = [componentsForToday month];

                        NSInteger currentYear = [componentsForToday year];





                        if (year == (currentYear-2000)) {

                            [sortedDateCurrentYearArray addObject:obj];

                        }



                        if (year == (currentYear-2000) && month == currentMonth) {

                            [sortedDateCurrentMonthArray addObject:obj];

                        }



                    }



                    NSMutableArray *sortedTimedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sortedDateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modTime" ascending:YES]]]];



                    [parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentDay addObjectsFromArray:sortedTimedArray];





                    NSMutableArray *sortedTimedCurrentYearArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sortedDateCurrentYearArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modTime" ascending:YES]]]];



                    NSMutableArray *sortedTimedCurrentMonthArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sortedDateCurrentMonthArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modTime" ascending:YES]]]];







                    [parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentYear addObjectsFromArray:sortedTimedCurrentYearArray];

                    [parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentMonth addObjectsFromArray:sortedTimedCurrentMonthArray];

                }




//                                    });



            }



        });



    }







    BOOL isFileAlreadyPresent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePathOnPhone];





}



NSMutableArray *sortedParsedDetailsArrayForCurrentDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[parsedDetailsDataArrayForCurrentDay sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"modTime" ascending:YES]]]];



NSDate *startDate ;

NSDate *endaDate;





dispatch_group_notify(d_group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self stopLogoSpin];

        [hud dismiss];



    });

    NSLog(@"All background tasks are done!!");

});


}
```

Now, logs @"Entered Thread " is visible in log but, @"Saved File in Database: %@", [[self.filesListArray objectAtIndex:i]  and @"Saved thread" are not called.

Also,

```
BOOL success = [appD.ftpManager downloadFile:[[self.filesListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"kCFFTPResourceName"] toDirectory:[NSURL URLWithString:dataPath] fromServer:srv];
```

helps download file with their seperate thread in the download method. 
Should uncommenting below help?

```
    //                dispatch_group_async(d_group, myQueue, ^{
```

Main thread is intentionally made to wait but this block below is also never called:

```
dispatch_group_notify(d_group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self stopLogoSpin];
        [radialHUD dismiss];

    });
    NSLog(@"All background tasks are done!!");
});
```

Please advice any modification and solution to problems above.

Comment: surely this is more of a disk I/O problem than a threading problem? core data isnt my strong point, but maybe optimizing how the data is written to the database / read should be optimized if it can be

Comment: yes @Fonix : that's exactly the concern. It takes ages to process. Multi-threading can help in this I guess, wherein I need to provide an incremental ID probably to each input and then while fetching I need to divide the whole bunch in multiple threads bifurcating in ranges of IDs. But I am not exactly sure how to go about it, or if this is of any help.

Comment: i dont think threading will help disk I/O, would probably even slow it down, but yes maybe you can read in a chunk of data, then on a separate thread, start processing it while you are loading the next chunk. depends how intensive the processing is whether it will be worth it or not. cant really say much based on the information you have given, and also i dont know too much about core data, so someone else might have to help you

Comment: Your downloadFiles method can be optimised. How big are the numbers in the for loops (self.filesListArray.count, result.count and currentFileComponentsArray.count)?

Comment: They range in thousands

Comment: downloadFiles will be faster if you move everything that won't change outside the loops (specificDay, dateFormatter, timezones). Don't copy the arrays. NSMutableArray can be sorted and addObjectsFromArray: adds objects from a NSArray. Don't sort definedResults. If you store correct dates in this century in the database, you probably can do three fetches for current day, year and month. I don't know if it will be faster. Take a look at Instruments and Time Profiling.

Comment: Will try that. But I needed to ask as in question and code above I have used a grouping of threads. Is that helpful? Should I stick with it, if yes, I am facing problem that some code is never called as mentioned in question above.

Answer (score 0):

Optimised the code by moving all what is not needed in loop outside and the performing the looping operation using GCD.

```
 dispatch_queue_t myOwnQueue = dispatch_queue_create([@"MyOwnQueue" UTF8String], NULL);

dispatch_apply(self.filesListArray.count, myOwnQueue, ^(size_t i) {   });
```

This lead to reduction in time by half. However any further optimisations need to be seen.